# Download File From Shared Dropbox Using Dropbox ApiError

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

Im looking to download a CSV file that is on a shared dropbox folder. The code that I currently have given me an `ApiError`. Full code and error below:

My Code:

```
import dropbox

ACCESS_TOKEN = '***MY ACCESS_TOKEN***'

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(ACCESS_TOKEN)

url = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s8vwbg46zjsg3rw/AAC0T1BhIgfp5BfH_sJ_Vnb1a?dl=0"
file = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s8vwbg46zjsg3rw/AAC0T1BhIgfp5BfH_sJ_Vnb1a?dl=0&preview=Stock+List+2021-03-08.csv"

md, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=file)

print(md)
print(res)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\***\PyCharm\Furniture\Test 1\dropbox_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    md, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=file)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 4181, in sharing_get_shared_link_file
    r = self.request(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py", line 346, in request
    raise ApiError(res.request_id,
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('90075839f9f94c53a112a48692314d4f', GetSharedLinkFileError('shared_link_is_directory', None))
```

Any help would be great. I have also tried `files_download` and I also get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s8vwbg46zjsg3rw/AAC0T1BhIgfp5BfH_sJ_Vnb1a?dl=0..." link itself points to a folder, not a particular file (whether or not you have the `preview` parameter on it).

Here are two ways you can make this work:

1. Supply the `path` parameter on [`sharing_get_shared_link_file`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file) to specify the file in the folder you want:

```
md, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=url, path="/Stock List 2021-03-08.csv")
```

2. Use the actual link to the file in particular (which I retrieved manually via the shared link page):

```
file = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s8vwbg46zjsg3rw/AABhEIN92e98iufhllgVuIvga/Stock%20List%202021-03-08.csv?dl=0"
md, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=file)
```

Also, if the file is in the connected account for the access token you're using, you should certainly be able to use `files_download` to download it. Feel free to open another question with the details of that issue if you wish.